# How to style choice field labels in symfony?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have multiple checkboxes in my form. I need to style every checkboxes' labels. What I want to do is described with the code below by the `choice_label_attr` field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,

        'choices' => array(
            'Friend' => 'friend',
            'Guide' => 'guide'
        ),

        // Invalid code, it serves for demonstration purposes
        'choice_label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'btn'
        )
    ));
}
```

How can this effect be achieved?

---

### Edit

It is possible to write something like this in the twig templates:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your Name', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

However, this technique is prone to code duplication.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain

Comment: I still can't understand what I did to deserve a downvote..

Comment: Your question is not bad. I'm not sure it's downvote-worthy, but I'd suggest editing to include what you've tried so far and the problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 3):

The `choice_label_attr` option may be part of symfony 3.1.

You can see the PR [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16834)

Comment: Thank you, I have already seen that pull request. Seems like there is no such option present in symfony right now.

Comment: 3.1 is not so far now :) Beta should begin by this end of the month for a release in May.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i styled them in the .twig file.
So my form is looking like this:`

```
 <div class="field">
    <div class="foo">
    {{ form_label(form.quantity) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.quantity) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.quantity) }}
   </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    {{ form_label(form.amount) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.amount) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.amount) }}
</div>`
```

You could also do:

```
<div class="field">
  <div = class="foo">
    {{ form_row(form.quantity) }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    {{ form_row(form.amount) }}
</div>
```

Here is the Symfony Doc: [Twig Template Form Function and Variable Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

To directly add a class to the field label: create a Directory in Ressources to override the template for FOSUserbundle. Ressources->FOSUserbundle->views->Security->login.html.twig
Here is my code for the login page. You may have to do this for every form.

```
    {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />
    </div>
        <div class="field">
    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
        </div>
            <div class="field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>
            </div>
                <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to style `<label>` tags directly, not with the outside wrappers. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    'label_attr' => array(
        'class' => 'btn'
    )
```

instead of

```
    'choice_label_attr' => array(
        'class' => 'btn'
    )
```

Comment: There is a difference between `label_attr` and `choice_label_attr`. The first one works for ONLY ONE label which is located in the wrapping div of the form element. What I want to do is to give the `btn` class to EACH radiobutton labels.

Comment: maybe think about adding it as hidden input and do the frontend hardcoded in the view, just update the hidden field accordingly